# How to use nest js guard with GraphQL file upload mutation?

Tags: nestjs, typegraphql, apollo-federation, graphql-federation, graphql-upload

I am implementing file upload functionality in Nest JS GraphQL with Federation. I am using graphql-upload library for file upload. I have encountered an issue that when i send an invalid JWT which is being checked in the guard , The guard is throwing the error which i can see in logs but Its not being received on GraphQL Client.

Another case is that when the code in mutation is being executed, it doesn't return any data before the whole stream is read. (We must read the stream to return anything from the mutation)

I have tried throwing the error from the the guard but its not being returned to graphql client